# How to scrape the yahoo finance search auto suggestion result with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to use selenium python to auto search on yahoo finance. When I type some words a suggestion will pop out like the same on google suggestion.

https://finance.yahoo.com/

I found a list element with the xpath should be the suggestions made by yahoo:

```
//*[@id="search-assist-input"]/div[2]/ul
```

It seems the suggestion content are hidden in this list, but it's invisible, I mean when I click to unfold it, it just goes away. I don't know if there's some sort of 'always unfold nodes' in firefox or chrome, but these elements seem very hard to reach.
I tried to get all the children under this element, it shows no element can be found:

```
from chrome_driver.chrome import Chrome

driver = Chrome().get_driver()
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='search-assist-input']/div/input")[0].send_keys('goog')
x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-reactid='56']/ul[@data-reactid='57']/*")
```

How can I reach these auto suggestion from the search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the *Auto Suggestions* with respect to the search text e.g. **GOOG** within the *Search Box* of `https://finance.yahoo.com/` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the auto suggestions to be **visible** and you can use the following solution :

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='p']"))).send_keys("goog")
  yahoo_fin_auto_suggestions = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='p']//following::div[1]/ul//li")))
  for item in yahoo_fin_auto_suggestions :
      print(item.text)
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  GOOG
  Alphabet Inc.Equity - NASDAQ
  GOOGL
  Alphabet Inc.Equity - NASDAQ
  GOOGL-USD.SW
  AlphabetEquity - Swiss
  GOOGL180518C01080000
  GOOGL May 2018 call 1080.000Option - OPR
  GOOG.MX
  Alphabet Inc.Equity - Mexico
  GOOG180525C01075000
  GOOG May 2018 call 1075.000Option - OPR
  GOOG180518C00720000
  GOOG May 2018 call 720.000Option - OPR
  GOOGL180518C01120000
  GOOGL May 2018 call 1120.000Option - OPR
  GOOGL.MX
  Alphabet Inc.Equity - Mexico
  GOOGL190621C01500000
  GOOGL Jun 2019 call 1500.000Option - OPR
  ```

Comment: nice, Can I ask how do you know it's stored in the li nodes? How should I check it with firefox/chrome?

Comment: @bot1 Those `<li>` tags are _ReactJS_ based tags and you can always  take out the `page_source` to examine the contents. As a shortcut I took  a snapshot to identify the child tags were `<li>` tags :)

Comment: ok, but when I click to expand the ul node, it simply fade away. How did you take a snapshot for it? I mean did you do it like pretty fast right after you click the expand?

Comment: @bot1 I shouldn't have rolled out the short cut in the first place :) let us follow the best practices i.e. `page_source`

Comment: Yes, I actually just realized this is exactly what I was looking for in another question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the source code of https://finance.yahoo.com/ website might has been changed, I have adjusted the answer of @DebanjanB in three points:

1. Click for accepting cookies / submit consent
2. Xpath for search field (at least for Germany/EU)
3. Xpath for suggestion list

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
#options.add_argument('headless') #optional for headless driver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit' and @value='agree']").click() #for cookie consent

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='yfin-usr-qry']"))).send_keys("goog")
yahoo_fin_auto_suggestions = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="_0ea0377c _4343c2a0 _50f34a35"])')))
for item in yahoo_fin_auto_suggestions:
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below please find a revised version in response to the latest changes on Yahoo Finance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
latest_news = ['Go to Latest News']

chrome_path = "C:\Python\SYS\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='yfin-usr-qry']"))).send_keys("goog")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="header-search-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/h3'),'Symbols'))

yahoo_fin_auto_suggestions = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'modules_list__1zFHY')[0].text.split('\n')
if yahoo_fin_auto_suggestions == latest_news:
    yahoo_fin_auto_suggestions = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'modules_list__1zFHY')[1].text.split('\n')


print(yahoo_fin_auto_suggestions)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).